# HTML: Trying to decrypt this url encoding

Tags: html

I have a crawler that scans a few websites and I'm unable to find this encoding structure, I was hoping it might look familiar to someone if not, it's worth a shot in the dark.

%3D-67%7C-40%7C-18%7C-105%7C114%7C50%7C-106%7C-119%7C6%7C-120%7C-31%7C-77%7C-86%7C-38%7C69%7C-74%7C54%7C-60%7C45%7C72%7C-21%7C52%7C-21%7C4

I was using http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp but i dont think this is acsii

Well i'm trying to follow this link.

http://www.autotrader.com/redirect/redirector_link.jsp?to_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.carfax.com%2Fcfm%2Fcheck_order.cfm%3Fpartner%3DATD_D%26vin%3D-67%7C-40%7C-18%7C-105%7C114%7C50%7C-106%7C-119%7C6%7C-120%7C-31%7C-77%7C-86%7C-38%7C69%7C-74%7C54%7C-60%7C45%7C72%7C-21%7C52%7C-21%7C45&mis=FCVDBDLNCF850&car_id=301290632&make=HONDA

And get back the VIN

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML?

Comment: Try here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 2):

Looks URL-encoded to me, the plaintext being

```
=-67|-40|-18|-105|114|50|-106|-119|6|-120|-31|-77|-86|-38|69|-74|54|-60|45|72|-21|52|-21|4
```

Now how to further interpret this I don't know, might be something custom. More context might help.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually URL-encoding. The result is something like this:
=-67|-40|-18|-105|114|50|-106|-119|6|-120|-31|-77|-86|-38|69|-74|54|-60|45|72|-21|52|-21|4

This looks a lot like a serialization of a byte[] value.

Can you give a little more context, like, for example, where does this string come from ?